# Teamcity not able to fetch codecommit repo over ssh

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, teamcity, aws-codecommit

Trying to integrate teamcity 9.1.1 with AWS code commit. I am getting "Connection successfull message" using ssh key which i have already uploaded to teamcity. but while building the project it shows "Failed to collect changes, error: Error collecting changes for VCS repository '"ssh" {instance id=39, parent internal id=9, parent id=Codecommit_Ssh, description: "ssh://repo-name#refs/heads/master"}'
'git fetch' command failed."

Any way to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got the Answer.. While entering fetch URL in VSC settings just put your SSH key ID that you get in AWS IAM console.
eg. ssh://APKA...@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/foo

This started working

Thanks